# Is destructuring assignment a shallow or deep copy?

Tags: javascript

I'm confused by the destructuring assignment about shallow and deep copy. For example,

```
const obj = {key:{}, value:{}}
let {key} = obj
key = {msg: 'hello'}
```

Is the value of `key` in the sample above a shallow or deep copy of the `key` in `obj`? What is the value of `key` should be?

Comment: Shallow copy only.

Comment: If you do `key.newProp = 10`, it will be reflected in `obj` because they are both refereceing the same object. But, `key = { }` is just changing variable's value. [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000)

Comment: But either way (shallow or deep), your `key = {msg: 'hello'}` assignment will have no effect whatsoever on `obj` or the objects in it.

Comment: Just for what it's worth, the word is "destructuring" (extracting something from a structure), not "destructing" (destroying).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> let {key} = obj
> ```

… is the same as saying:

```
let key = obj.key
```

It is a shallow copy.

---

> ```
> key = {msg: 'hello'}
> ```

… overwrites the reference to the object that also exists in `obj.key` with a reference to a new object.

This renders the previous line pointless as nothing was done with the value before it was overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

It's shallow, though there's some nuance.

This:

```
let {key} = obj;
```

has exactly the same result as this:

```
let key = obj.key;
```

E.g., all it does is copy the value of `obj.key` into `key`, making both of them point to the same object — a shallow copy, if the word "copy" really applies. (Normally I think of a "shallow copy" as copying multiple properties, not just one, like `Object.assign` does.)

You can reach deeper into the object graph you're retrieving from by using nested destructuring:

```js
const obj = {
    a: {
        b: {
            c: {
               d: "hi",
            },
        },
    },
};
const {a: {b: {c}}} = obj;
console.log(c.d); // "hi"
```

but at the end of the day it's just like an assignment, so it's just grabbing the object reference (if the value is an object reference), not a copy of the object:

```js
const obj = {
    a: {
        b: {
            c: {
               d: "hi",
            },
        },
    },
};
const {a: {b: {c}}} = obj;
console.log(c.d);         // "hi"
console.log(obj.a.b.c.d); // "hi"
c.d = c.d.toLocaleUpperCase();
console.log(c.d);         // "HI"
console.log(obj.a.b.c.d); // "HI"
```

---

**But**, even if it were a deep copy, your code still wouldn't change anything in `obj`, because you're changing the value of what's in `key` (an object reference), not the state of the object that reference refers to. After `let {key} = obj`, `key` is completely disconnected from `obj.key` other than that they both refer to the same object. If you change the value in `key`, the *variable*, it has no effect on the object it refers to. If you're goign to do `key = ...`, there's no point to `let {key} = obj` at all, just use `let key`.

Comment: Your answer is quite a detail along with useful for me, any +1

Comment: (FWIW, I go into destructuring in a fair bit of detail in Chapter 7 of my recent book, *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.)